# For the PROD environment I have to use the same variable, but with a different value. How to do it?

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, production-environment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline that uses variables from Library. For the IN, QA, and STAGE environments, I use a variable from shared variables. But now I need to create a PROD environment and deploy to PROD. And only for the PROD environment I have to use the same variable, but with a different value. How to do it?

Because if I add a special variable for PROD, I will have to change it in CI, in the build. Then the wrong variable will be used for INT, QA and STAGE.
And I plan to make the deployment on PROD dependent on the build and the deployment on STAGE as in the picture:

[image]

Comment: From your question I really don't understand why you can't declare a separate variable for PROD. you can choose to use variables conditionally based on the env. Anyway kindly include a Minimum reproducible example to get maximum help from the community. Minimum reproducible example in your case would be the pipeline yaml.

Comment: when I create another variable for PROD, then in the build pipeline I will need to change this variable, but then INT, QA and STAGE environments will not work.

Comment: Variables in the build pipeline are distributed to CD in INT, QA and STAGE. They are declared at the beginning of the CI pipeline and also work in templates for deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pipeline variable with the same key as in other environments and value as the values you want for PROD then select the stage to PROD. In this way it will override the value for production environment with the value you set in the pipeline variable

Answer (score 1):

You could create and clone the variables group in your library and give the different value to the groups and assign the different groups to different stages in pipeline variable groups link management.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have variables group at 1 level of build pipeline that variables regarding INT, QA and STAGE environment. And at 2 level I have variables group for deployment to PROD environment. When pipeline is executed, it uses level 1 variables for INT, QA and STAGE. And then, when the deployment to PROD comes, it uses level 2 variables. And despite the fact that in variables groups we have one variable with different values, it uses the last value, i.e. level 2 variables.